# where clause SQL in JSP

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

Could anyone tell me why my SQL statement does not work in JSP. I copy the output of the string to oracle, it works as intended. Is this statement correct?

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT disc||crs_num FROM crs_sec_schedule_reader where'" +sqlString+"' ");
```

Following is the detail of the codes:

```
String sqlString;

sqlString = "crs_sec_schedule_reader.semester = '" + semesterAdjusted+"' ";


if(!department.equals( "Select All"))
{
sqlString += " and discipline_schedule_reader.discipline_name = '" + department+"'";
}

if (div_undr.equals("null") && div_grad.equals("G"))
{
sqlString += "and crs_sec_schedule_reader.D_E_G ='" + "G"+"'";
}
else if (div_undr .equals("U") && div_grad.equals( "null"))
{
sqlString += " and (crs_sec_schedule_reader.D_E_G = '"+ "D" +"' or     
crs_sec_schedule_reader.D_E_G ='" + "E"+"')";
}
else
{
sqlString += "and (crs_sec_schedule_reader.D_E_G = '" + "D" + "' or  
crs_sec_schedule_reader.D_E_G ='" + "E"+"'or crs_sec_schedule_reader.D_E_G = '"+"G" 
+"') ";
}



.....

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT disc||crs_num FROM crs_sec_schedule_reader    
where'" +sqlString+"' ");
```

Comment: Print out the complete generated SQL statement and look at it carefully & post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Single quotes around `sqlString`.

Where you have

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT disc||crs_num FROM crs_sec_schedule_reader where'" +sqlString+"' ");
```

I believe you want

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT disc||crs_num FROM "
  + "crs_sec_schedule_reader where " +sqlString);
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident it is. Remember his `sqlString` also contains single quotes. Make sure there's a space after where too.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing space quote after `where`, use below statement.

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT disc||crs_num FROM crs_sec_schedule_reader where '" +sqlString+"' ");
```

or

> sqlString = "  crs_sec_schedule_reader.semester = '" +
>   semesterAdjusted+"' ";

Answer (score 0):

That single quote after the `where` looks suspect to me

you'll end up with

```
where 'crs_blah_blah ......
```

but do as Matt suggests - print the full sql statement and see what it looks like. These things are always fiddly.

Answer (score 0):

Space should be after WHERE Clause

**(WHERE condition)**

```
String sqlString;
// Your Code Goes Here...
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT disc||crs_num FROM crs_sec_schedule_reader WHERE TRUE AND '" + sqlString + "' ");
```

**Use Prepared Statement to Prevent the SQL Injection**. Try following example:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
while (rs.next()) {
    String userid = rs.getString("USER_ID");
    String username = rs.getString("USERNAME"); 
}
```